# workflow 4.0 bookmark not updating in database‏

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I am working on Windows Workflow Foundation 4.0 project having native and service host activities in it. I am using SQL 2008 R2 as my backend.

I have several activities in the workflow, most of which should place bookmark in the database so that next activity could be resumed from there. when the first activity places a bookmark in the database, it is resumed  by the second activity quite well, but when the second activity wants to place a bookmark in the database, the bookmark is not updating itself from the previous bookmark and also, no exception is raised in the code.

I am new to Workflow foundation, please advise if i am doing something wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The best way to know what is going on is to capture the tracking data.  Just create a class which derives from TrackingParticipant and add it to the Extensions collection.